# How do I set line number in VI Editor

Tags: vim, vi

I am using the VI editor in Ubuntu and I have maximum usage of VI editor.
to see the line number in vi i am using like below:

```
:set nu
```

I want to set it default when I open a file in vi editor, that file text open with line number by default.

is it possible?

Sorry for duplicate's if it but I search it lot first but not found easily also tried :colorscheme now it is showing me **unknown**

Comment: By the way, you might like to ask Vim-related questions on the [Vi and Vim StackExchange site](http://vi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: vi ~/.vimrc
Error detected while processing /root/.vimrc:
line    3:
E185: Cannot find color scheme ':default'

Comment: O.o You don't have to use *those* settings - the relevant point is that `~/.vimrc` is the file to be modified.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could add this to your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
set number
```

But if you want that to happen only on files with `txt` extension:

```
autocmd BufReadPost *.txt set number
```

or perhaps better, on any file which Vim detects is a text file:

```
autocmd FileType text set number
```

Comment: Thanks @joeytwiddle it works !! just tried by editing # vi ~/.vimrc  and enter _set number_ in the file and Save it by _:wq!_